# Selecting unique values per rows in pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

I have this custom object:

```
**Id | Name | User**

1  | A | {Joe, Joe, Chloe, Cindy}

2 | B | {Joe, Andy, Andy, Cindy, Cindy}

3 | C | {Joe, Joe, Chloe, Chloe, Andy, Andy}
```

I need to sort unique users for each individual object like below:

```
**Id | Name | User**

1  | A | {Joe, Chloe, Cindy}

2 | B | {Joe, Andy, Cindy}

3 | C | {Joe, Chloe, Andy}
```

I need to output the ID or Name after sorting.

The closest I could get was to run a `| sort-object -unique`, but it doesn't work as I was not able to pull the individual IDs/Names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "Select-Object" with a hashtable (also known as a calculated property):

```bsh
$objects | Select-Object Id,Name,@{ Name = "User"; Expression = { $_.User | Select-Object -Unique } }
```